# Show autocomplete dropdown only after type at least 1 letter in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material, angular-material2

I would like to implement an autocomplete using Angular 2+ with [angular material design](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview) where the options should not appear unless they've typed at least 1 letter.

By default, the autocomplete is toggleable on focus even when the input is empty, so I want to change this behavior.

I have tried to add a condition on mat-autocomplete element `*ngIf="inputField.value"` in order to display the options only if the input has value, but it returns the error:

Error: Attempting to open an undefined instance of `mat-autocomplete`. Make sure that the id passed to the `matAutocomplete` is correct and that you're attempting to open it after the ngAfterContentInit hook.

Also, I have tried to add a condition into `[matAutocomplete]="auto"` on the input field, but it also returns error.

I noticed that when the autocomplete options are being displayed, the elements `cdk-overlay-container` and `mat-autocomplete-panel` are created before close `</body>`, and they are unlinked with the original  component, so it difficult to hide by css.

Do you have ideas how to do that?

Please follow the code on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qxd4hq?file=app/autocomplete-filter-example.html).

Thanks!

Comment: you have to write a custom pipe function .

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Do not call the filter function if the typed text's length equals 0.

```
this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
  pipe(
     startWith(''),
     map(val => val.length >= 1 ? this.filter(val): [])
);
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qxd4hq-uvkyyc)